# JavaFX backgroundImage disappearing when shrinking window

Tags: java, css, user-interface, javafx

I have a JavaFX project in which I define a background as following:

```
setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundImage(new Image("/images/Achtergrond.png"), BackgroundRepeat.ROUND, BackgroundRepeat.ROUND, BackgroundPosition.DEFAULT, BackgroundSize.DEFAULT)));
```

The background is present and enlarging screen enlarges my background but as soon as I shrink the screen/window to anything less then 720p (background image size) it doesn't shrink the background image but it just goes away leaving me with a blank white background. how can i make it so it also shrinks instead of only enlarging?

Comment: not sure about this but you maybe should use `BackgroundSize:Cover` 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BackgroundSize.html

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by declaring my background using CSS instead of hard coding it in javafx...